# Does Apple Watch automatically stop walk/run workout?

Tags: apple-watch

One problem I commonly have with activity and workout trackers is that I forget to stop recording when I finish my walk or run, and end up including a bus ride or drive as part of the workout. This skews the data and mostly makes it useless for tracking.

And furthermore, most trackers don’t make it easy to trim or crop an activity after it has been completed.

Does the Apple Watch automatically stop recording a walk or run workout when it detects you’re moving faster than a human could possibly run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://www.imore.com/how-use-workout-detection-apple-watch).

For watchOS 5, you can use the Workout Detection to remind you to start and stop a workout.

> After you physically begin a workout but forget to tell your watch about it, **you'll receive a tap on the wrist after a few minutes along with a notification on the watch face**. On this message, you can tap to confirm and record the workout, change the workout type, mute the notifications for the day, or dismiss the information. Regardless of your choice, the Apple Watch will continue to track the workout back to the time it began.
>
> Subsequently, **if you forget to stop a workout on the watch, you'll receive a similar message after a few minutes of inactivity**. The notification will ask you to confirm the end of the exercise, change the workout type, mute the notifications for the day, or dismiss the information. Again, you'll still get credit for the workout regardless of your selection.

[image]

1. Push the Digital Crown on your Apple Watch.
2. Tap the `Settings` app.
3. Scroll down to `General`.
4. Tap `Workout`.
5. Turn on `Start Workout Reminder` and `End Workout Reminder` by sliding the switches to the left.

[image]

Do the opposite to turn them off.

### Exercise routines that are compatible with Auto-Workout Detection

To date, the following exercises support Auto-Workout Detection:

- Indoor Walk
- Outdoor Walk
- Indoor Run
- Outdoor Run
- Elliptical
- Rower
- Pool Swim
- Open Water Swim

Answer (score 3):

watchOS 6 (set to release in fall 2019) will include enhancements to automatic workout detection.

- [Apple Watch: All of the health and fitness features, explained](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/apple-watch-fitness-features/)

> #### Automatic workout detection
>
> When the Apple Watch senses you're beginning a workout, you'll get an alert asking if you want it to start tracking. You can respond to that notification to choose your workout type and beyond a session.
>
> Best of all, if you missed out on a few minutes before beginning to track the workout, Apple Watch will give you retroactive credit for that, too. And if you forget to stop tracking when your workout is over, the Apple Watch will detect that and automatically end it.